# Byte-Buddy-Android for current Dx

Tags: android, byte-buddy, dx

I'm currently using *byte-buddy*, *byte-buddy-android* and Android's *dx_1.7* library. The *dx_1.7.jar* is out of date (2012) and I wonder if someone has already built a new *byte-buddy-android.jar* that works with a current *dx.jar* (not *dx_1.7.jar*) provided by a more current Android SDK. How would I achieve something like this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you actually stuck? What's the actual problem?

Comment: I have tried to rebuild byte-buddy-android with the new dx and it failed because of static method translate() not found.  I saw that the translate method between the 2 dx versions are taking in different parameters.  I thought of modifying the AndroidClassLoadingStrategy.java with the new register method but not sure how to get the DirectClassFile and DexFile parameters.

Comment: I will try to get the DirectClassFile from the String file name and the DexFile from the DexOption.  I'm new to byte-buddy, if you have any suggestions, please advice me.

Comment: A `DirectClassFile` instance can be created by instantiating it, the file path needs to be set to some dummy value and strict parse can be any value. A `DexFile` instance can be created by passing the `DexOption` instance to it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the outdated dependency is that Google does not distribute newer versions of their compiler via Maven Central or any other central repository. Therefore, it is outdated.

However, this should not cause any trouble as the dex compilation should be able to process any Java code even if it depends on newer Android APIs. If you, for some reason, require to use a newer version of the DX compiler, you need to recompile the module using the newer DX compiler API.